# Display (map) list of messages nested in an object (MERN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am learning MERN and would like to display the list of messages from Mongo Database in React UI.

**My UserSchema in Mongo:**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phone: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  
  messages: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      phone: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      message: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  tokens: [
    {
      token: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

**Code in Home.js in React:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState({});
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const userHome = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("/userdata", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });

      const data = await res.json(); //successfully getting complete json data in console.

      console.log(data);
      setUserName(data);
      setShow(true);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    userHome();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="page-wrap d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
              <span className="display-1 d-block">
                <p> Welcome {show ? "Back!" : ""} </p>
                <h1>{userName.name}</h1>
                <h2>
                  {show
                    ? "What you want to do today?"
                    : "Your own Portal.."}
                </h2>
              </span>
              <div className="mb-4 lead">
                {show
                  ? ""
                  : "You need to register and login for accessing your profile."}
              </div>
              <div>
                <div>Messages:{userName[0].message}</div> 
            {/* wants to display list of all message here */}

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**My approach to try fetching the list of all messages**

I tried map method but not succeeded and tried below code still no success. Kindly advise. I want to display all the messages Message 1, Messag 2 etc. upon loading.

```
<div>Messages:{userName[0].message}</div>
```

Error Message in Browser:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')
```

**I got it solved as below**

Removed

```
<div>Messages:{userName[0].message}</div> 
        {/* wants to display list of all message here */}
          </div>
```

Added:

```
 <div>
   {userName.messages?.map((msg1) => (
     <li key={msg1._id}>{msg1.message}</li> ))}
 </div>
```

Comment: The messages are in the `messages` property so to access the text of the first message you need to use `userName.messages[0].message` If you don't understand this(and it's really simple stuff) maybe you should learn the basics of javascript first.

Answer (score 0):

can you delete this part:

```
              <div>
                <div>Messages:{userName[0].message}</div> 
            {/* wants to display list of all message here */}

              </div>
```

and add this instead:

```
  <div>{
    data.map(result => (
      <div key={result._id}>
          <h2>{result.name}</h2>
          <p>Some text: {result.messages}</p>
      </div>
    ))
  }</div>
```

If above code works, then you can tweak it to display your desired message which i think is this:

```
<p>Some text: {result.messages[0].message}</p>
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy!
I found out the solution already, updated it in my query section.